# Unit Testing XQuery

Tags: unit-testing, xquery

I've been working with a document repository using XQuery (via Java and .NET interfaces) and was wondering if anyone has any recommendations for unit testing XQuery modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick DIY type solution for this problem:
<strike>[Poor man's unit testing with XQuery](http://jimfuller.blogspot.com/2007/09/poor-mans-unit-testing-with-xquery.html)</strike> (dead link).

This approach seems to have been embraced and extended for the tests of the [xprocxq](http://code.google.com/p/xprocxq/source/browse/trunk/main/test/) project.

Other tools exist, for example [XTC](http://www.fgeorges.org/xslt/xslt-unit/).

Answer (score 3):

There are several XQuery unit testing frameworks, but most are special-purpose written for a specific XQuery Processor. This is not a complete list, but includes most of the popular ones I'm aware of:

**MarkLogic**

Roxy Unit Tester https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Unit-Testing

XQUT https://github.com/mblakele/xqut

xray https://github.com/robwhitby/xray

**eXist**

XQSuite http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xqsuite.xml

**BaseX**

XQuery Unit Module http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Unit_Module

Comment: There is also XSuite which lets you run XQSuite tests as JUnit tests

Comment: @adamretter, is there documentation for XSuite? I only see it mentioned in eXist release notes.

Comment: Not exactly. XSpec javadoc can be seen here: https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/blob/develop/test/src/org/exist/test/runner/XSuite.java#L46
One of many examples of it being used can be seen here: https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/blob/develop/test/src/xquery/dates/DateTests.java#L28

Let me know if you need more info on XSuite...

Comment: The Roxy repo now has a banner that says "This repository has been archived by the owner on Nov 9, 2022. It is now read-only."  MarkLogic-unit-test https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-unit-test looks like a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This link may spruce your development. This is just an idea but you can develope and enhance more on this with various unit-test case design ideas.

since Xml is a king in meta-data world its quite easy to design and run.

1. design a Test-Case Xml by having all details capture

   1. test-data ( input & expected result )
   2. test-case id
   3. test-case local methods
2. invoke dynamically based on the details.

[functions](http://thewallaceline.blogspot.com/2009/04/xquery-unit-tests.html)

[sample test script](http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/xmlwiki/UnitTest2/Tests/unittests.xml)

[results](http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/xmlwiki/UnitTest2/runTests.xql?uri=/db/Wiki/UnitTest2/Tests/unittests.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Try [XQSuite](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xqsuite.xml?q=xquery%20unit%20test&field=all&id=D1.2.8#D1.2.8)

It's pretty slick; here's the "minimal example":

`declare namespace test="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqsuite";`

`declare function %test:assertEquals("Hello world") local:hello() {
    "Hello world"
};`

Additionally, [XSpec](https://code.google.com/p/xspec/wiki/GettingStarted) works wonderfully for XSLT testing (provides nicely formatted HTML test results, for example) BUT appears to need a bit of work with XQuery testing.  The project appears to have become inactive in the past few years.